# CompareTo on Date Aspect of an ArrayList of Objects

Tags: java, sorting, date, collections

I am attempting to use the Collections.sort(arraylist) functionality to sort an object that contains a date object. I want to order the arraylist so that the dates determine where in the arraylist they are sorted.

Currently no sorting occurs. I am uploading all the files contained in a directory and taking lines out of those files and those files contain the date. However, the Collection.sort functionality does not  appear to be doing anything. The files are sorted as they arrive.

I will have a brief example of how the sorting is happening and then my code.

Sorting:

```
"2015-08-05 13:18:59.199","RFBase-TD","40","Device message","S",";0CC4: F2FF: 04C7: pitv1"
"2015-08-24 08:45:13.977","RFBase-TD","40","Device message","S","0028:  00 63 7E 21  00CA: "
"2015-08-18 11:35:48.891","RFBase-TD","40","Device message","S",";0006: 8490: 0000: ltpv4"
"2015-08-12 14:30:42.778","RFBase-TD","40","Device message","S",";1066: 6E25: 00C7: bctv1"
```

Code from main.java:

```
private static ArrayList<logObject> rftdArrayList = new ArrayList<logObject>();

private static void createFolderChooser(final JFrame fcFrame) throws IOException
{
    resetArrayLists();

    int i = 1; int j = 1;
    fcFrame.setVisible(true);
    String filename = File.separator+"tmp";
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File(filename));
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY); 
    fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fcFrame);
    lblFileChosen.setText("Folder Chosen: "+ fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
    File[] files = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().listFiles();
    LogFileTA_1.setText(null);
    System.out.println(files.length);
    for ( File file : files ) {
        System.out.println(file.getName());
    }
    if (files.length != 0)
    {
        JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        Border border = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Calcualating...");
        progressBar.setBorder(border);
        fcFrame.add(progressBar);
        fcFrame.setVisible(true);

        double percent = 0;
        int intPercent = 0;
        progressBar.setValue(intPercent);

        for (File f : files)    
        {
            if (f.isFile())
            {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;
                String text = null;

                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
                    String line = null;

                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) 
                    {
                        if (line.contains("RFBase-TD")){
                            rftdArrayList.add(new logObject(line,i));
                            if (i<10)
                            {
                                LogFileTA_1.append(i+")      "+line);
                                LogFileTA_1.append("\n");
                            }
                            else if(i<100)
                            {
                                LogFileTA_1.append(i+")    "+line);
                                LogFileTA_1.append("\n");   
                            }
                            else if(i<1000)
                            {
                                LogFileTA_1.append(i+")   "+line);
                                LogFileTA_1.append("\n");   
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                LogFileTA_1.append(i+") "+line);
                                LogFileTA_1.append("\n");   
                            }
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }
                j++;
                percent = 100*(j/files.length);
                intPercent = (int) (percent + 0.5); //Adds .5 in order to round.
                progressBar.setValue(intPercent);
            }
        }
        if (rftdArrayList.size() == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            LogFileTA_1.setCaretPosition(0);
            logFileResults();
        }   
    }
    else 
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmRftdAnalyzer, "Folder contains no RFTD log files", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}

private void initialized()
{       

        mntmOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                errorTree.setModel(null);
                createFileChooser(frmRftdAnalyzer);             
            }

        });
}
```

Code from logObject.java:

```
public class logObject implements Comparable<logObject>
{
    protected String logEntry;
    protected int lineNumber;
    protected String time;
    protected String device;
    protected String deviceThrough;
    protected String deviceArea;
    protected String endTime;
    protected String timeElapsed;
    protected int endLine;
    protected String dateAndTime;
    protected Date date;
    protected SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);

    public logObject(String logEntry, int lineNumber)
    {
        this.logEntry = logEntry;
        this.lineNumber = lineNumber;
        this.time = logEntry.substring(12,24);
        this.dateAndTime = logEntry.substring(1,24);
        try {
            this.date = formatter.parse(dateAndTime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(date.getTime());
        this.device = null;
        this.deviceThrough = null;
        this.deviceArea = null;
        this.endTime = null;
        this.endLine = 9999;
        this.timeElapsed = null;
    }
    public String getLogEntry()
    {
        return this.logEntry;
    }

    public void changeTimeElapsed(String timeElapsed)
    {
        this.timeElapsed = timeElapsed;
    }

    public long getDateTime()
    {
        return this.date.getTime();
    }

    public Date getDate()
    {
        return this.date;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(logObject o) 
    {
        return this.getDate().compareTo(o.getDate());
        //return Long.valueOf(getDate().getTime()).compareTo(Long.valueOf(o.getDate().getTime()));
    }
```

Comment: Please can you post code which shows how elements are added to the list, and then how organizeArrayList() is invoked.

Comment: I added the code, the actual name for organizeArrayList() is actually createFolderChooser(). I have updated everything accordingly.

Comment: There is a lot of code here which obscures understanding of the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Your example code is not invoking `Collections.sort` anywhere. Could you add that part?

Comment: Hey Mick, I had the Collection.sort in the wrong place, because I have two very similar functions. Things seems to be sorted correctly now. Thank you!